# Avoiding Raw Loops and using std::algorithm instead

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to follow the advice given, among other place, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8&list=PL0IJqh3Gjgo2dfreKafVN8siMoIiW21lc) to avoid  raw loops and use `std::algorithm` instead. So I would be thankful if you could help me do that, if possible, in the following case:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::vector<Object> v;
for (const auto& curr : v) { ss << curr.ToString() << '\n'}
return ss.str()
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: what benefit do you expect here from using an algorithm? I mean with `auto` and a ranged based loop your code is already as C++11 as it can get and you can use that loop with any other container without changing anything on it. As I understood, biggest benefit of algorithms is that they work on any container, but this is already the case for your code.

Comment: take a look at `std::ostream_iterator`

Comment: @tobi303 I'm not actually sure. Just trying to follow the advice, maybe it's wrong :)

Comment: *"Avoiding Raw Loops"* sounds like a Sean Parent quote, or a quote based on his talks/work. Parent himself allows *trivially* correct loops, such as the one in your code. I would agree that this loop is fine and need not artificially be replaced by some algorithm.

Comment: I watched the video and around 29:40 he makes an argument for range based for loops to be preferable to an algorithm (specifically `for_each`)

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you can just run:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const Object& o) { ss << o.ToString() << '\n'; });
```

Which is equivalent to

```
for(const auto&& curr : v)
{
  ss << curr.ToString() << '\n';
}
```

This seems like this may be a case where a loop is OK. In fact, if you look at the `std::for_each` code, it just internally runs a loop, so it may be overkill.

Comment: Furthermore, if we have `operator<<` defined for `Object`, `std::bind(operator<<, ss)` can be used in place of the closure? :)

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty concise:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Object>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

It would only work if `operator<<` is appropriately defined, for example

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Object& obj)
{
    return ostr << obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You confused ostream with operator&

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to follow the advice given, among other place, here to avoid raw loops and use std::algorithm instead.

Now why do you want to do that?

The example Sean Parent used in the first seven minutes or so of his talk was indeed a horrendously bad example of code. The code was terribly convoluted and it went on and on and on. However, transliterating that awful mess of multiple `for` loops with nested logic within into various calls to the algorithms library would have been even worse. Parent missed the most important coding guideline of all (read with humor):

> Always write your code as if the person who will be assigned to maintain it is a psychopathic *blub* programmer who knows where you live.

If you're a good programmer, you have to temper your desire to make your code as smart and cool and compact as can be against the fact that many other people will read your code. This tempering becomes natural when you become an excellent programmer.

I'm not saying you need to dumb your code down to the level where it becomes --C rather than C++. That said, part of being a good programmer considering the poor *blub* programmer who has to read and maintain that code. On you're striving to be an excellent programmer, one aims to write code that sets an example for all of code that is concise and efficient, and yet at the same time is obvious and is eminently understandable.

This might mean well mean stifling the urge to use the deepest and darkest corners of the C++ utilities, algorithms, and type traits libraries.

Comment: I quite like the answer. One should not follow the advice blindly and apply it where the advice becomes counter-productive.

Comment: Note that Sean was very clear that this was a *guideline*, rather than a *requirement*.

Comment: @MarshallClow -- Where in my answer did I say this was a *requirement*? I'm saying that this is even worse: I'm saying it's a bad guideline. Functional programming is a foreign paradigm to most C++ programmers. I've programmed in Lisp; I'm quite familiar with functional programming. Most of my C++ cohorts are not. I have learned that I need to to stifle some of those very cool lessons I learned from Lisp.

Comment: I am afraid you misread his message. He never advocated algorithm library for the sake of algorithm library. The most important part of the guideline is that _A loop is an algorithm. It does something important. It deserves a name. Please please understand its functionality, isolate it,  and factor it into the function._ The less important part of the message is that STL indeed has many useful algorithms, and chances are you can use it.